# How to set an image source in code-behind inside a library?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, bitmapimage

I have a class library written in C# for Windows 8 with a custom control and a folder called Images with bunch of images in it. In control template I have an image

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Image x:Name="MyImage"
               Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
               Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
               Stretch="Fill" />
               ...
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I want to set in this control's code-behind one of that images (which are inside this class library) as a source for this image.
What I have already tried:

1. Absolute uri using `FrameworkElement.BaseUri` with both Do Not Copy and Copy Always property values of images:

   ```
   this.MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri, imagePath));
   ```
2. Relative uri with both Do Not Copy and Copy Always property values of images:

   ```
   this.MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.Relative));
   ```
3. `ms-resource` uri scheme.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that escalated quickly. :) Maybe, will be useful for others.
The solution is to use assembly name of the library in the path:

```
var assemblyName = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
this.MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri, assemblyName + imagePath));
```